# Why are the width and height of a element directive calculated as 0?

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, angularjs-directive

On a project I'm currently working on, I have directives with `restrict: 'E'`.

At some point in my app, I need to know the hight of one of these directives but no matter how I try
to determine the width and height of the directive, I always get 0.

I've found some similar questions, but the solutions didn't help as the questions were primarily about
finding the height/height of `$element` inside the directive controller/linker. In my case,
the code that tries to find out the dimensions is outside of the directive-linker. In fact, the
directives have been already inserted in the DOM for a while.

The code looks like this:

```
// the directive
app.directive("widget", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            config: "="
        },
        ....
    };
});
```

```
<!-- the view -->
<widget config="config" ng-attr-id="{{ config.id }}"></widget>
```

And this is the function that tries to get the dimensions of that `widget` directive

```
function widget_dimensions(id)
{
    var $w = $('#' + id);

    if($w.length != 1)
        return;

    return {
        width: $w.width(),
        height: $w.height(),
    };
}
```

This function always returns `{ width: 0, height: 0}` when I pass a real `widget` id.

I prepared a [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/shaoran/nmpy34vu/51/) that demonstrates this. The directives are already in the DOM.
The only function that returns a non-0 on the element directive is `getBoundingClientRect()`,
but here the height is 68.9px and it should be 50px.

Why is this happening? I've read the [`$compile`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) documentation a few times, hoping to find
something that I've missed before.

I use google-chrome Version 67.0.3396.87 for linux. I tested my
[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/shaoran/nmpy34vu/51/) on Chromium 57.0.2987.98 and Vivaldi 1.15.1147.47 and I got the same
results. However the same test on Firefox 60.0.2 yields the correct result. Is this a bug in
chrome family of browsers? Or is it a webkit/blink problem?

**EDIT**

As [Lex](https://jsfiddle.net/shaoran/nmpy34vu/51/) points out in the comments, this might not have anything to do with angular after all.
I've [updated my jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/shaoran/nmpy34vu/64/) which now prints the `display` property.

Now chrome **and** firefox say

```
$d1.css("display"): block
$d2.css("display"): inline
```

It's interesting that `<dtest2></dtest2>` is an inline element even though it behaves like a block
element. Still, chrome and firefox behave differently when it comes to calculating the dimensions.
Which one is correct?

Comment: I think this is more of an HTML/CSS thing than an AngularJS thing. If you add `style="display: block;"` on your `<dtest2>` element the width and height are properly calculated.

Comment: @Lex I've updated my jsfiddle and you're right, `<dtest2></dtest2>` is an inline element, even though it behaves like a block element. Still I'm wondering which browser behaves correctly.

Answer (score 1):

As being said adding 'display: block' fix all issues, and in both firefox and chrome you get 52px (Cause borders are also counted).

Problems without 'display: block' is related to fact that you should not put block (i.e. div) inside inline (i.e. span).

P.S. 
you can use `clientWidth`, `clientHeight` instead of this pretty `getBoundingClientRect`.
you can see same height and width in dev console.
you should not use jquery and methods like function(id) in angular app